# Post meta as array looks like string instead of array

Tags: post-meta, array

I want to insert an array into a post meta, but something strange is happening.
What am I missing here?

**How I insert meta to a post:**

```
// 1st Quarter
for ($month = 1; $month <= 3; $month++) {

  $last_day = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
  $first_date = strtotime("$year-$month-$first_day 00:00:00");
  $last_date = strtotime("$year-$month-$last_day 23:59:59");

  $month_dates = array(
    'name' => 'P' . $month . '-FY' . $year,
    'start_date' => date('Y-m-d', $first_date),
    'end_date' => date('Y-m-d', $last_date),
    'closed' => 0
  );
  array_push( $tmp_period, $month_dates );

} // end for

$quarter_name = 'Q1-FY' . $year;
add_post_meta( $post_id, '_q1_name', $quarter_name, true );
add_post_meta( $post_id, '_q1_subs', $tmp_period, false );
```

**How I check the inserted meta:**

```
$subs = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $subs, false );
echo '</pre>';
```

**What the inserted meta actually looks like:**

```
Array
(
    [_q1_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Q1-FY2018
        )

    [_q1_subs] => Array
        (
            [0] => a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:4:"name";s:9:"P1-FY2018";s:10:"start_date";s:10:"2018-01-01";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"2018-01-31";s:6:"closed";i:0;}i:1;a:4:{s:4:"name";s:9:"P2-FY2018";s:10:"start_date";s:10:"2018-02-01";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"2018-02-28";s:6:"closed";i:0;}i:2;a:4:{s:4:"name";s:9:"P3-FY2018";s:10:"start_date";s:10:"2018-03-01";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"2018-03-31";s:6:"closed";i:0;}}
        )
)
```

**What I originally expected the meta to look like:**

```
Array
(
    [_q1_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Q1-FY2018
        )

    [_q1_subs] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array (
                   'name' => 'some name',
                   'start_date' => some start date',
                   'end_date' => some end date,
                   'closed' => some value
            ),
            [1] => Array (
                   'name' => 'some name',
                   'start_date' => some start date',
                   'end_date' => some end date,
                   'closed' => some value
            ),
            [2] => Array (
                   'name' => 'some name',
                   'start_date' => some start date',
                   'end_date' => some end date,
                   'closed' => some value
            ),
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data will be [serialized](http://php.net/manual/de/function.serialize.php), if you save non-scalar values (e.g. array, object) as post meta. You must [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php) it:

```
$subs = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
$subs['_q1_subs'][0] = unserialize($subs['_q1_subs'][0]);
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can unserialize it before I add it as post meta?

Comment: The data will be serialized when saving to the database, because you cannot save unserialized data. So it must be serialized while adding it as post meta. You must unserialize it after getting the post meta.

Comment: Got it...didn't know Wordpress serializes it by design. Thanks man!